# Waterlock permission deined

Tags: node.js, bash, sails.js, waterlock

i am new to use waterlock, but when i finished install waterlock using npm install waterlock and then npm install waterlock-local-auth so i go to next step in the [doc](http://waterlock.ninja/documentation/) . but i have result `bash: ./node_modules/.bin/waterlock: Permission denied`
 and then i try to use chmod 755 , chmod 777 with `./node_modules/.bin/waterlock` success but when i type waterlock generate all the result is `waterlock command not found` , please help me how to make it waterlock run.

the answwer very appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem with install your node with stable version this is work fine for me, when the problem show i use node development and install via source.

Hopefully can help :D

Comment: I use NVM to install node - no need for sudo :)